# How to get IntelliJ to use Java7 for Google App Engine dev server?

Tags: java, google-app-engine, intellij-idea, java-7

I'm using IntelliJ as my IDE, and I want to run my Google App Engine app using Java7.  However, when I run the app, the logging window shows

```
C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_37\bin\java" -javaagent:C:/Users/Andy/Dev/tools/google-app-engine/appengine-java-sdk-1.8.0/lib/agent/appengine-agent.jar [etc...]
```

What I've done:

1. installed JDK7 into C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_04
2. in IntelliJ's "Project Structure" window, under Platform Settings/SDKs, I've added a Java SDK called "1.7" which points to the folder from step 1.
3. in IntelliJ's module settings for my app's module, I've set the Module SDK to the "1.7" SDK created in step 2
4. When that had no effect, I set the JAVA_HOME environment variable to the JDK7 folder (previously it pointed to the JDK6 folder) and restarted IntelliJ. Still no effect.

I'm stuck.  Ideas?

Comment: Update: I discovered that if I change the Project SDK to 1.7 (it was 1.6), it works.  Apparently there is no correlation between run configurations and modules; my mistake.

Comment: Heh, way to solve your own question!  Good job.

Comment: Your comment should probably be an answer instead (... and perhaps you could even get some upvotes for it then ....).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is to change the project-level SDK; IntelliJ's Run/Debug configurations don't respect their associated module's module-level SDK setting.

I've logged a bug on this in the JetBrains issue tracker:
http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-122860